# How to pass variables as context to IBM Cloud Watson Assistant with V2?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am trying to use the new [API version V2](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant-v2?language=python#send-user-input-to-assistant) for [IBM Cloud Watson Assistant](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/index.html#about). Instead of sending a message for a workspace I need to send a message to an assistant. The context structure has global and skill-related sections now.

How would my app pass in values as context variables? Where in the structure would they need to be placed? I am using the Python SDK.
I am interested in sending information as part of [client dialog actions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions).

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: added info about Python SDK

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the SDK where only 3 documented variables are sent as part of the context https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/issues/597. The developer is looking at the problem but I don't think it will get fixed before Monday

Comment: I tried context->skills->main skill->user_defined and it seems to work

Comment: @GermanAttanasio I updated my answer with complete cURL request and response for your reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404249/watson-assistant-api-v2-manages-the-context-automatically-more-details/53406037#53406037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on testing the Python SDK and the API V2 using a [tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool), I came to the following conclusion. Context is provided by the assistant if it is requested as part of the [input options](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant-v2?language=python#send-user-input-to-assistant).

```
  "context": {
    "skills": {
      "main skill": {
        "user_defined": {
          "topic": "some chatbot talk", 
          "skip_user_input": true
        }
      }
    }, 
    "global": {
      "system": {
        "turn_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
```

To pass back values from my client / app to the assistant, I could use the context parameter. However, in contrast to the V1 API I needed to place the key / value pairs "down below" in the **user_defined** part:

```
context['skills']['main skill']['user_defined'].update({'mydateOUT':'2018-10-08'})
```

The above is a code snippet from this [sample file](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/blob/master/handleClientActionV2.sample.py) for a client action. With that placement of my context variables everything works and I can implement client actions using the API Version 2.